# Outlook 2007 Won't Connect With Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

I just moved a company to a new office location, but the client computers running Outlook 2007 won't connect to the Exchange 2010 server.

The company has a new static IP address, but all of the MX records have been updated already. Plus, this really seems like an internal issue anyway.

The company is all on one domain.

Outlook web access works just fine, as do all of the smartphones. Email can be received and sent, and calendars and contacts sync properly

Any ideas why Outlook won't connect?

Comment: On a side note, MX records are unrelated to Outlook connectivity. See what this tool shows: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

Comment: Yes I know, but I figured I'd provide as much info as possible. Thanks for the link

Comment: With Outlook running, hold down CTRL and right-click on the Outlook icon in the system tray. Choose 'Test Email Autoconfiguration'. That should provide information about why Outlook can't talk to Exchange.

Comment: @NathanG, thanks for that tip, I didn't realize that was an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little silly, but as it turns out not all the services started up with the Exchange server, specifically the RPC Client Access Service.

A quick trip to services.msc and 'start' for the RPC Client Access Service fixed the issue. Thank you everyone for the suggestions and help!

Comment: Great, glad you've got this working. Be sure to mark this answer "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a problem of authentication, so try the following steps:

Go to->Account Settings>Change>More Settings>Security>And now change:

> Negotiate Authentication

to:

```
Password Authentication
```

If you continue with the same error, then shows the error message  that appears when you try to access Outlook.

Comment: Thanks Voislav, I tried your suggestion, but it did not fix the issue for me.